# Three JS randomPointsInGeometry always gives box shape

Tags: three.js, geometry

Im trying to make a particle system adapt to a certain geometric shape, I am using THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry and can and array from this that I can then position particles however regardless of the geometry I use (primitive or dae) the particles fill the space of the geometry bounding (I presume) and always fill a box shape.

The key lines

    `var object = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.OctahedronGeometry( 50, 2 ), new 
    THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} ) );
    var positionsX = 
    THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry(object.geometry,  20000);`

Full running code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/joe_shields/5sbcfzqt/5/

Any Ideas what I need to change to ensure that the particles honour the shape fo the original geometry?

[image]

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: You have a bug in your code. Step through with a debugger so you can find it yourself.

Comment: oops - imports were wrong, thanks for spotting-
 resolved.
https://jsfiddle.net/joe_shields/5sbcfzqt/

Comment: So switching from BufferGeometry to Geometry resolved the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/joe_shields/2xt1q9h8/